# HTML5 navigation menu text

Tags: html, css, nav

I am trying to make a navigation bar with `<nav>` in HTML5 with a simple text and 3 links. This is pretty basic, but the text of my links gets mixed up and I don't know why.

↪ [See my code at JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5ruLj/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to float your `LI`, not your `UL`. No need for `position:absolute`. If you want to move the menu to the right, you **can** float it as well, or use `margin:left`. Just be sure to clear your floats after.

See my tutorial: [I Love Lists](http://preview.moveable.com/jm/ilovelists)

Answer (score 1):

it was because of the position:absolute and position:relative parts in your css.

Try this :

```
nav {
    width:100%;
    height:181px;
    display: block;
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/JrTUv.png') top no-repeat;
    margin-top:30px;
}
nav ul {
    float:right;
    list-style:none;
}

nav ul li {
    display:inline-block;
}
```